Why are orbitals are stable even though they have wierd shapes?
I'm curious to know about why are they stable, let's talk about $p$-orbital , $p$-orbital is dumbbell shaped shouldn't electrons just fall into the nucleus because we need a centrifugal force to counteract the nuclear attraction so electrons should revolve around nucleus

"Orbital" is a terrible, misleading name. The macroscopic thing they are like is not an orbit, but a "mode" of a vibrating object.

Centrifugal force is a concept appearing only in a rotating reference frame. That is not the reference frame where the probability density shows the dumbbell shape. Moreover, the electron does not "revolve" around the nucleus. That is a classical concept, not compatible with Quantum Mechanics.

The failure of classical mechanics to correctly predict the behavior of electrons in atoms was a driving force to the discovery of quantum mechanics. See my answer to Why doesn't an electron ever hit (and stick on) a proton?

The only electronically "stable" state of an atom is its ground state (assuming that the nucleus is stable). All the excited states are decaying into a ground state by emitting photons.

What you have pointed out is actually an issue with Classical Mechanics. Electrons are small enough that their behavior is dictated by Quantum Mechanics.
On that scale, electrons behave like waves, rather than particles (until they are observed). Orbitals are solutions to the equation called Schrödinger's Equation. You can think of them as 3D standing waves.

This is a commonly taught mental model, but it is, unfortunately, misleading. Quantum mechanics is not the behavior of "small" objects. It's the behavior of systems with small angular momentum and charge. It is not the electrons that are behaving like waves. It's the quantum mechanical ensemble of electrons and nuclei that is near its ground state that shows this behavior.
